# How do we plot images at given coordinates in R?

Tags: r, image, plot, scatter-plot, cran

Given 'n' images in a png/jpeg format and 'n' corresponding coordinates in 2 dimensions (x,y): I would like to plot these images at the given coordinates on a single plot. If I find the images to be too big, I would ideally like to plot them as a smaller/scaled version at the given coordinates. How can i achieve such a plot in R?

An example of how such a plot would look is given below:

[image]

Comment: @baptiste i'd require to plot then at 2d coordinates. The arguments for rasterImage have 4: (xleft 
a vector (or scalar) of left x positions.

ybottom 
a vector (or scalar) of bottom y positions.

xright 
a vector (or scalar) of right x positions.

ytop 
a vector (or scalar) of top y positions. )  How should i comprehend that and fit it as a solution to my question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
xy <- data.frame(x=runif(10, 0, 100), y=runif(10, 0, 100))

require(png)
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

thumbnails <- function(x, y, images, width = 0.1*diff(range(x)), 
                       height = 0.1*diff(range(y))){

  images <- replicate(length(x), images, simplify=FALSE)
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))

  for (ii in seq_along(x)){
    rasterImage(images[[ii]], xleft=x[ii] - 0.5*width,
                ybottom= y[ii] - 0.5*height,
                xright=x[ii] + 0.5*width, 
                ytop= y[ii] + 0.5*height, interpolate=FALSE)
  }
}

plot(xy, t="n")
thumbnails(xy[,1], xy[,2], img)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if img is a list of different images, you need to comment out this line: images <- replicate(length(x), images, simplify=FALSE) for it to work

Comment: How would one specify a list of 10 different images in a specified location, that correspond with 10 co-ordinates?

Answer (score 4):

The `my.symbols` function along with `ms.image` function (both from the TeachingDemos package) can be used to plot with images.

Here is an example:

```
library(png)

flag.list <- lapply( list.files('flags/',pattern='png$', full=TRUE), 
    function(x) readPNG(x) )

library(TeachingDemos)

ms.flags <- function(ind,...) {

    tmp <- array(0, dim=c(150,150,4) )
    tmp[ 26:125, , 1:3] <- flag.list[[ind]]
    tmp[ 26:125, , 4 ] <- 1

    ms.image(tmp,...)
}

x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)

my.symbols(x,y, symb = ms.flags, ind=1:50, symb.plots=TRUE,
  add=FALSE, xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(-3,3), inches=0.75)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying this but I get "Error in flag.list[[ind]] : subscript out of bounds" and I see that flag.list is "List of 0"....it seems i'm not getting the images?

Comment: @val, what did you do to read in the images?  did you download some images? which folder are they in relative to your working directory?

Comment: I used this line: imgfiles <- list.files(getwd(),pattern="*-scaled.png") to get my images. I ended up posting my answer here using the code from the accepted answer above - see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37150889/r-plotting-thumbnails-that-are-in-a-list-on-a-scatterplot

Answer (score 2):

the [ggflags package](https://github.com/baptiste/ggflags) provides a proof-of-principle example

```
library(ggflags)
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(50), y=rnorm(50), 
                country=sample(c("ar","fr", "nz", "gb", "es", "ca"), 50, TRUE), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, country=country, size=x)) + 
  geom_flag() + 
  scale_country()
```

[image]